# Resource filtering with SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

I need to achieve something like Maven filtering, but with SBT:

1. read a .properties files
2. replace all instances of ${some.property} in a "filtered" resource file with the values read from the properties file

How to best achieve that with sbt?

(I checked the xsbt-filter plugin and a sbt-properties plugin, but I don't know how to even get started)

Comment: You found the right thing, [xsbt-filter](https://github.com/sdb/xsbt-filter) and you should follow the instructions on that link. Perhaps your question is more about how one uses sbt?

Comment: well, you have to read properties from a properties file first, and then run the plugin (the instructions are not entirely clear, and besides - the plugin is not found in neither maven central nor sonatype..)

Comment: It [is there](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/github/sdb/xsbt-filter_2.9.2_0.12/), but a little dated requiring Scala 2.9. Perhaps just look at how it was implemented and create your own plugin?

Comment: Hi, have you already reslove this? if there are tow filter files in `src/main/filters`: test.properteis and product.properties. How to choose which one to be used?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what do you mean by _"filtered" resource_? Why not just including the file at your `application.conf`, or the configuration file that starts with the process?